# 'new FormControl', is mandatory for reactive forms - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've implemented my forms by using reactive forms in Angular project. Here I'm using formGroup and 'new FormControl' for creating fields. Now I'm having a doubt like is there any way to implement fields without using Formcontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use FormBuilder. Like this:

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'; 

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

this.productForm = this.fb.group({
  productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                     Validators.minLength(3),
                     Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  productCode: ['', Validators.required],
  starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
  tags: this.fb.array([]),
  description: ''
});
```

Notice that there is no `new FormControl()` required.

See the documentation for more information here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder